# custom lstlisting environment

Tags: listings, environments, minipage

I'm using the `listing` package for displaying source code in my document.
I want to use the `minipage` environment to avoid page breaks within the listing, but I don't want to write, at every listing,

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
... code goes here ...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

I've tried to define a new environment, like so

```
\newenvironment{codeListing}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{lstlisting}}{\end{lstlisting}\end{minipage}}
```

for using it like this

```
\begin{codeListing}
... my code ...
\end{codeListing}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `listings` package provides `\lstnewenvironment` for such cases. Try `\lstnewenvironment{codeListing}{\minipage{\linewidth}}{\endminipage}`

Comment: `\newenvironment` no longer works, you should use `\lstnewenvironment`.